# homeomorphism between the closure of the sphere minus one point and the sphere itself

Tags: general-topology

anyone can help me with this problem, how can I prove that there is an homeomorphism between the closure of the (sphere minus one point) and the sphere itself any ideas?

thank you very much

Comment: Do you know what the closure of $S^2\setminus\{p\}$ looks like?

Comment: It seems to me that closure(sphere minus a point)=sphere.

Comment: @Mercy: Exactly. Which makes it pretty easy to find the homeomorphism: you just have to show that the closure adds only one point, and that that point ‘looks’ like the one that you removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Show that $\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R^3}(S^2\setminus\{p\})=S^2$.

Comment: thank you for the replies, I have the same intuitions as you all, but I don't know how to show this formally. any ideas?

Comment: Show the two sets are the same, and use the identity mapping.

Comment: @user42912: Let $X=S^2\setminus\{p\}$. Let $x\in\Bbb R^3\setminus X$, and show that if $x\ne p$, then $x\notin\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R^3}X$, while $p\in\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R^3}X$. HINT: If $x\in\Bbb R^3\setminus S^2$, then $\|x\|\ne 1$.

Comment: thank you all, I will think about it.